# Javascript - Subarray Sum Equals K

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I am just looking at some interview questions and came across this guy

```
Given an array of integers and an integer k, 
you need to find the total number of continuous subarrays whose sum equals to k.

Example 1:
Input:nums = [1,1,1], k = 2
Output: 2
```

I know I can loop over and do this in more of a long winded way, but I am wondering if I can use `reduce`.

I have the following which is failing when I pass it the following arguments:

`subarraySum([-1,-1,1], 0)`

```
const subarraySum = (nums, k) => {
    let answer = 0;
    nums.reduce((acc, val) => {          
        if(acc + val === k) {
            answer++;
            return val;
        }
        if(val === k) {
            answer++
            return val
        }
        return acc + val;
    }, 0)

    return answer;
};
```

Comment: This is not a new problem, and certainly not unique to JS: did you remember to [search](/help/how-to-ask) first?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I know this, but I am wondering if this can be solved using `reduce`?

Comment: Anything a for loop can do, `reduce` can do, so the short answer is "of course" but the more detailed answer is "rewrite your question if all you want to know is whether reduce can do the job"

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure one of the answers here is correct. I added an example in a comment under it. For my own answer, I added a brute force comparison to the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `reduce` is quite convenient here in order to answer the question in linear time, as it lets us both update and revisit accumulating values.

JavaScript code with comparison against brute force at the end:

```js
const subarraySum = (nums, k) =>
  nums.reduce(([map, sum, answer], val) => {     
    const newSum = sum + val;
    answer += newSum == k;
    answer += map[newSum - k] || 0;
    map[newSum] = (map[newSum] || 0) + 1;
    return [map, newSum, answer];
  }, [{}, 0, 0])[2];

console.log(subarraySum([-1,-1,1], 0));
console.log(subarraySum([1,-1,1,-1], 0));


function bruteForce(A, k){
  let result = 0;

  for (let windowSize=1; windowSize<=A.length; windowSize++){
    for (let start=0; start<A.length-windowSize+1; start++){
      let sum = 0;

      for (let end=start; end<start+windowSize; end++)
        sum += A[end];
      
      if (sum == k)
        result += 1;
    }
  }

  return result;
}


var numTests = 500;
var n = 20;
var m = 20;
var kRange = 10;

for (let i=0; i<numTests; i++){
  const A = new Array(n);
  for (let j=0; j<n; j++)
    A[j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * m) * [1, -1][Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
  
  const k = Math.floor(Math.random() * kRange);

  _f = subarraySum(A, k);
  _brute = bruteForce(A, k);

  //console.log(String([_f, _brute, k, JSON.stringify(A)]));

  if (_f != _brute){
    console.log('MISMATCH!');
    console.log(k, A);
    console.log(_f, _brute);
    break;
  }
}

console.log('Done testing.')
```

Comment: you can add an array as the first argument to `reduce`?

Comment: @peterflanagan you can add anything you want.

Comment: yep, only thought that after 

Comment: Can you please explain how this is working ?

Comment: @ChinmoySamanta the map is actually recording prefix sums since we just keep adding. To calculate the sum of a contiguous subarray, we have `prefix_j - prefix_i = sum`. In this case, we are looking for `k` so `prefix_j - prefix_i = k` => `prefix_j - k = prefix_i`. In the code, `map[newSum - k]` is like `prefix_j - k` and we're checking if we have a count for `prefix_i`, which is the value that the key, `newSum - k`, is pointing to if it exists.

Comment: @ChinmoySamanta (I also added a brute force check to the code snippet to make sure this was working :)

Comment: In this code, `map` would be much better named `prefixes`, or even better, `prefixCounts`.  To understand the performance improvement, you can play around with [this microbenchmark](https://jsbench.me/9gktx350oi/1).  Do note that this is nearly linear in memory usage, although that's not likely a problem these days.